# How to insert image in sql using PHP oops

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning PHP with object oriented programming and want to help me to insert image in database. what can i do?

Normally the data is inserting without the image but not able to enter the data with the image. So please help out with this issue.

```php
protected function create()
{
    $this->validate();
    if (!empty($this->errors)) {
        return false;
    }
    $attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . static::$table_name . " (";
    $sql .= join(', ', array_keys($attributes));
    $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
    $sql .= join("', '", array_values($attributes));
    $sql .= "')";
    $result = self::$database->query($sql);
    if ($result) {
        $this->id = self::$database->insert_id;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

DATA IS INSERTING WITHOUT THE IMAGE BUT IM TRYING TO THE INSERT THE DATA WITH THE IMAGE SO PLEASE HELP ME OUT

Comment: protected function create() {
    $this->validate();
    if(!empty($this->errors)) { return false; }


    $attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . static::$table_name . " (";
    $sql .= join(', ', array_keys($attributes));
    $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
    $sql .= join("', '", array_values($attributes));
    $sql .= "')";
    $result = self::$database->query($sql);
    if($result) {
      $this->id = self::$database->insert_id;
    }
    return $result;
  }

Comment: You should do some basic debugging, what properties are in the `attributes` array (Does it include an image key / value)? In which format are you trying to save the image and does it match with the databases expectation for it? You should also look into prepared statements, sanitising your attributes is not enough to prevent sql injection.

Comment: For security reasons: Use PDO and prepared statements to build the INSERT statement.

Comment: what does the function `sanitized_attributes` do? i doubt it protects against SQL injections correctly?

Comment: so what can i do help me

Comment: sanitized_attributes protect against sql injections

Comment: *"sanitized_attributes protect against sql injections "* how? Do you use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`  ?  Show the function code... Also you should show more general code stuff like HTML form and where you handle the file upload as this code is very incomplete..

Comment: function sanitized_attributes() {
    $sanitized = [];
    foreach($this->attributes() as $key => $value) {
      $sanitized[$key] = self::$database->escape_string($value);
    }
    return $sanitized;
  }

Comment: what can i do to insert image

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```html
<html>
<body>
<?php
$msg = '';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $img = file_get_contents($image);
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','admin') or die('Unable To connect');
    $sql = "insert into images (image) values(?)";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s",$img);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $check = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
    if($check==1){
        $msg = 'Image Successfullly UPloaded';
    }else{
        $msg = 'Error uploading image';
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <button>Upload</button>
</form>
<?php
    echo $msg;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See this tutorial, This might help you

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jYZDJ-twqh8

Also check the source code at 

https://youtubephpschool.blogspot.com/2016/06/how-to-upload-and-display-image-from.html

Comment: Don't use this tutorial. It is outdated and it won't work.

Comment: so what can i do buddy